# What's wrong with my macro function?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, newline

I defined a multi-line macro function using line continuation character "\" like the following:

```
#define SHOWMSG( msg ) \ 
{ \     
    std::ostringstream os; \     
    os << msg; \     
    throw CMyException( os.str(), __LINE__, __FILE__ ); \ 
}
```

But it could not pass compilation. BTW, I'm using VS2008 compiler. Would you please tell what's wrong with my aforesaid macro function?

Comment: @Chad: James answered my question. That's "trailing spaces are not allowed after \ continuation character." Thank you for your attention.

Comment: The biggest problem with your macro is that it's a macro. Write a (possibly inline) method, and throw your exception where everyone can see it (though obviously not from the `ShowMsg()` method.) I know *you* know that SHOWMSG means "show and message and then throw a message", but it's not at all obvious to anyone else that a seemingly innocuous string display function would also be a control flow statement.

Comment: @dlef:  How do you propose to use `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` without a macro?

Comment: In gcc it works fine (though it gives warning): http://www.ideone.com/IwLh4

Comment: @James Fair point. I could see them being passed in as params, though that's maybe inelegant. I suppose my issue isn't with the macro per se, so much as with the naming. SHOWMSGANDTHENTHROW would seem better.

Comment: @dlev: it doesn't even show the message... simply THROW_MY would be better, and it should use a `do { ... } while (false)` construct or other workaround for the `if`/`else` chaining problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Multiple_statements)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual method for a multi-statement macro is something like:

```
#define SHOWMSG(msg)                                  \
do {                                                  \
    std::ostringstream os;                            \
    os << msg;                                        \
    throw CMyException(os.str(), __LINE__, __FILE__); \
} while (0)
```

Without that, the semicolon following the closing brace can cause syntactic problems, such as:

```
if (x)
    SHOWMSG("This is a message");
else
    // whatever
```

With your code as it was, this would expand to:

```
if (x) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "This is a message";
    throw CMyException(os.str(), __LINE__, __FILE__);
}
;    // on separate line to emphasize that this is separate statement following
     // the block for the if statement.
else
    // whatever
```

In this case, the semicolon would form a null statement following the block in the `if` statement, and the `else` wouldn't have an `if` to match up with.

Comment: +1 for `closing brace can cause syntactic problems`. I really din't notice that before.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: You solution takes one thing with another. Thank you very much. Sorry for my late response because I've just come back.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash must be the last character on the line in order for the line to be continued.

Some of your backslashes have spaces after them.

Comment: @Mr. Jame McNellis, Thank you very much. "Some of your backslashes have spaces after them". Yes, I did pay attention the trailing space(s) of "\" character.

Comment: That's not necessarily true -- the "end-of-line" indicator that's mapped to a new-line in phase 1 could be (for example) "an arbitrary amount of whitespace followed by a new-line". OTOH, that's certainly not required, in which case you're absolutely right.

Comment: @Jerry:  That's an interesting point; I had not considered that before.  That said, even with that possibility, the first sentence of this answer is still true (where "last character" is read "last character before the end of line indicator," which I think yields an accurate concept of what a line is) and the second sentence is merely an observation.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hit `Ctrl+Shift+8` in Visual Studio editor and see any whitespaces appearing after the trailing `\` - remove them!

Comment: Thank you! Hitting "Ctrl+Shift+8" can help to see any whitespace after the trailing \.